# Keep terminal open after an Alt+tab

Tags: terminal, manjaro

I'm using archlinux on Manjaro and am facing an issue.

I regulary use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> to switch between windows, especially the terminal window and others. The problem is, using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> on Manjaro to quit a terminal window, closes it, or puts it in background, and I can't go back to it using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> again.

I have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> (command to summon a terminal) to have it back.

Does anyone know how to change this feature and keep the terminal open as a normal window?

Answer (score 1):

> I have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> (command to summon a terminal) to have it back.

That behaviour is caused by the default manjaro configuration for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, which runs `xfce4-terminal --drop-down`. The `--drop-down` option creates a single-instance terminal window that does not appear in the ALT-TAB list. If you want the standard windowing behaviour for terminals you create from the shortcut, you can edit the entry in Settings->Keyboard->Application Shortcuts and remove the `--drop-down`.

### Further reading

The man page definition of `drop-down`:

> Will start the window in drop-down mode (also called a Quake-style
> terminal). This will only apply to the first window started with
> this option. It is advised to bind this to a shortcut in the
> keyboard preferences.